# echo records for each functions separately in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two function called `page_num()` and `messages()` and both function pass `$data` to the same `view admin/admin_messages`. how do I `echo $records` for each functions separately.

```
function messages(){
$data['records'] =  $this->mod_contactus->get_records();
$this->load->view('admin/admin_messages',$data); 
}

function page_num(){        
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('tbl_contactus', $config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
$this->load->view('admin/admin_messages',$data);
}
```

Comment: this is not possible do it in one function

Answer (score 0):

do it in one function

```
function page_recs(){
    $data['records'] =  $this->mod_contactus->get_records();   
    $data['page_records'] = $this->db->get('tbl_contactus', $config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_messages',$data);
}
```

in view

```
foreach($records as $record){
    //code
}
```

and

```
foreach($page_records as $page_record){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a global variable? something like "
    $this->records_messages = $data['records']
one for each function?